# Laplace transform of $(t-2)^2u_2$

Tags: laplace-transform

The homework problem is
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t < 2\\ (t-2)^2 & t\geq 2\end{cases}$$
$f(t)$ as a step function
$$f(t) = (t-2)^2u_2(t)$$
Using what we learned in class
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)u_c(t)\} = e^{-cs}\mathcal{L}\{f(t+c)\}$$
$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ should be
$$e^{-2s} \mathcal{L}\{f(t+c)\}= e^{-2s} \frac2{s^3}$$
but the answer in the back of the book is
$$e^{-s} \frac2{s^3}$$

I can't figure out why the answer does not include the 2 in the exponent.

Comment: I see nothing wrong at all with your answer (even verified it with Mathematica).

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Must be a problem in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just, work out the problem from scratch

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt =  \int_{0}^{\infty}(t-2)^2u_2(t)\,e^{-st} dt = \int_{2}^{\infty}(t-2)^2e^{-st} dt$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty}u^2e^{-s(u+2)} du= e^{-2s}\frac{2!}{s^3}, $$

which matches your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to verify it with mathematica and I have concluded the answer in the textbook is wrong.

> LaplaceTransform[Piecewise[{{0, t < 2}, {(t - 2)^2, t >= 2}}], t, s]

Comment: `Simplify[LaplaceTransform[(t-2)^2*UnitStep[t-2],t,s]]` works as well.